# Auto Populate TextBox with current Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, visual-studio

I am using AngularJS, HTML5 in an aspx page to create Visitor Check-in info:-

```
   <div style="border: dotted 1px grey; padding: 20px 0 20px 0; width: 40%;">
                <div class="row" style="margin-left: 30px">
                    <div style="display: inline-block;">
                        Visitor: 
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 28px; width: 383px;">
                        <input type="text" data-ng-model="currentUser.Visitor">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top: 20px"></div>
                <div class="row" style="margin-left: 30px">
                    <div style="display: inline-block;">
                        Title: 
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 40px;">
                        <input type="text" data-ng-model="currentUser.Title">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top: 20px"></div>
                <div class="row" style="margin-left: 30px">
                    <div style="display: inline-block;">
                        Visitee: 
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 24px;">
                        <input type="text" data-ng-model="currentUser.Visitee">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top: 20px"></div>
                <div class="row" style="margin-left: 30px">
                    <div style="display: inline-block;">
                        Arrival:
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 25px;">
                        <input type="text" data-ng-model="currentUser.Arrival">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top: 20px"></div>
                <div class="row" style="margin-left: 30px">
                    <div style="display: inline-block;">
                        Departure:
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 0px;">
                        <input type="text" data-ng-model="currentUser.Departure">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div style="margin: 2% 0 0 8%; display: inline-block">
                    <button data-ng-click="addNew(currentUser)" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Add New Check-in</button>
                </div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48m4ecfj/2/%0A)

I want the **field for the Arrival to be auto-populated**... so in my Main.JS, I am trying to say:-

```
var now = new Date();
$scope.currentUser.Arrival = now.format("dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm tt");
```

now.format() ... is not native js...but the function works as it is, just doesn't populate into the textbox.

But that is not working... It disables my angular grid and all data previously entered.. Main.JS  starts out like:-

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);
 app.controller('UserController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
 var now = new Date();
 $scope.currentUser.Arrival = now.format("dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm tt");
 $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'userList',
    columnDefs: [{ field: 'Visitor', displayName: 'Visitor' },
        { field: 'Title', displayName: 'Type of Visit' },
        { field: 'Visitee', displayName: 'Visitee' },
        {field: 'Arrival', displayName: 'Arrival Time'},
        {field: 'Departure', displayName: 'Departure Time'}]
  };... etc etc... fucntionalities....
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in http://jsfiddle.net or http://codepen.io ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHen I run that in JSFiddle, I get the error that now.format is not a function.

ANy reason you cannot use the Angular $filter?  Pass it into your controller:

```
app.controller('UserController', ['$scope', '$filter', function ($scope,$filter) {
```

Then assign the date:

```
$scope.currentUser.Arrival = $filter('date')(new Date(),'dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm a');
```

also, another side note is that from what you gave us, the currentUser is not yet defined for $scope, so the Arrival property will not be assigned.  If you've otherwise defined $scope.currentUser, then you're good.  Otherwise, you probably want that to look like:

```
$scope.currentUser = {};
$scope.currentUser.Arrival = $filter('date')(new Date(),'dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm a');
```

Comment: Thanks Beartums. This is my first time using AngularJS so not very familiar with it.. the learning curve.

Comment: 2philo, no worries.  We've all been there.  I promise, it gets much easier :)